# How to push data to vue instance

Tags: javascript, vue.js, push

I have a simple vue instance, where I want to have empty array as data.vueFlashes.:

```
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        vueFlashes: []
    }
});
```

and the component defined like:

```
<template>
    <transition name="fade">
        <div id="flash-component" v-show="visible">
            <span class="hide" @click="hide()">X</span>
            {{message.message}}
        </div>
    </transition>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        mounted: function() {
            console.log('VUE component mounted.')
        },

        created: function()
        {
            this.show();
        },

        props: [
            'message'
        ],

        data: function() {
            return {
                visible: true
            }
        },

        methods: {
            show: function()
            {
                this.visible = true;
                setTimeout(() => this.hide(), 5000);
            },
            hide: function()
            {
                this.visible = false;
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Then I want to fill the vueFlashes from outside this way:

```
// This is Laravel blade template
<script>
...
@foreach (session('flash_notification', collect())->toArray() as $message)
    app.vueFlashes.push( {!! json_encode($message) !!} );  // Error
@endforeach
...
```

But it throws me an error: **Cannot read property 'push' of undefined**
If I use temporary js array and then assign it to app.vueFlashes it works:

```
<script>
...
let jsFlashes = [];
@foreach (session('flash_notification', collect())->toArray() as $message)
    // jsFlashes.push( {!! json_encode($message) !!} );
@endforeach

app.vueFlashes = jsFlashes;  // This works fine
```

What is the difference between this two approaches where both of them call the same app.vueFlashes value?

Comment: What is `@foreach` from?

Comment: it is Laravel blade template. There is a comment in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<ul id='app'>

  <li v-for='flashMessage in flashMessages'>
    {{flashMessage}}
  </li>

</ul>
```

.

```
const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      flashMessages: [
        "Hellow. Something is wrong!",
        "Another message",
      ],
    };
  },
});


app.flashMessages.push("A message from Push");
```

Here's a minimum viable example: https://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/fyb0j5rt/

You'll need to narrow it down.

It's telling you that `app.vueFlashes` is undefined. That's probably because it's somewhere in a different scope... or something / but the error is real - so, listen to that - and track down why it's not defined where you're using it.

Comment: I have two scripts. First defines const app = new Vue and the second script calls app const but it is not defined. Console.log() says that first script app is vue instance and in the second console.log() the app is undefined. How?

Comment: Maybe the definitely comes after you are trying to use it? Maybe in different scopes? Are they both on the window? Do they go through a build process? Maybe put a console.time - next to each and see what order? It's really hard to answer a question like this - when we just have a bit of text here... and you have a bigger application.

Comment: So it seems Laravel app.js which instantiates the app variable is really in its own scope. As I write window.app = new Vue() it works. It little messy app.js is really huge... Thanks for help with the scope suggestion.